# iPhone 11 Pro Max lagging/freezing when using any app

Tags: iphone, ios, software

I have iPhone 11 Pro Max since 2019, and it worked perfectly fine until last week ( mainly few days after updating to the latest iOS) where all the apps keeps on freezing/lagging. If I text on WhatsApp for example, the screen becomes unresponsive for few seconds and everything freezes out and can't type or see any motion in the screen ( even if someone sends me a message I don't receive anything and can't even quit the app).

Also on other apps like Twitter, Instagram, Facebook, Safari, and all the apps. Not sure what's going on but this issue is happening to me since last week and it happens very often, every few minutes which is very annoying.

So anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the phone?  This would be the first step Apple would take to diagnose any issues if you brought it to them personally.  You'll want to ensure you have a back up done, first.

Comment: Yeah, this is likely a problem that could easily be fixed by backing up the phone to your computer, do an Erase All Content And Settings (Settings>general>Reset) and then restore from the backup you just made. That solves a multitude of iOS issues.